# fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly (Writing objects: 100%)

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I found few cases but they arent the same, in this case, the git says writing object completed,
and then it fails, any idea why?

The is the powershell console:

```
Counting objects: 1554, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1540/1540), done.
efrror: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 413 84 KiB/s
atal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Writing objects: 100% (1554/1554), 492.13 MiB | 5.49 MiB/s, done.
Total 1554 (delta 102), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the same problem when pushing to a remote repository over http that had been redirected (via apache on the server) to https.

e.g. `git push http:<blah>` failed
but `git push https:<blah>` worked

Comment: ok i'll try it, i also trying http://www.btaz.com/misc/fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly/ this solution, the issue is that it takes up to 2-3 hours to upload all the files and then it fails, very annoying.